# Will my server cluster/DB solution work or is there a better alternative?

Tags: database, server

## Brief

I'm working on a project where an app will communicate with a database via an API, however my experience with balancing server loads of this scale is limited.

I'm under NDA so I'll try to explain the setup as best as possible, please let me know if there's any details that you need to help understand!

The database will hold information that is likely to change on a 30-second basis.

The difficulty comes with scalability - we're possible to be having thousands of concurrent users so making sure that the server stack can handle the load (and is scalable) is a priority.

I've simplified the lifespans of back- and front-end for explanation purposes:

**Back-end**

1. External source sends an XML file with latest data
2. CRON job runs every 30 seconds to see if files have been updated, then parses and inserts updated data into database A
3. CRON job runs every 30 seconds to (a) pull data from database A (b) use algorithms to calculate data based on the data from database A (c) input this new data into database B

**Front-end**

1. User runs and signs into app
2. App periodically makes calls to API to retrieve/push data to database B

---

## Cluster

After preliminary discussions, this is the server cluster so far:

- CDN
- Load Balancer (to distribute requests to the openmost Web Head)
- Web Head* (to handle the API request)

  - Session Server (to handle app authentication only)
- Redis* (to store cached queries and reduce load on Database)
- Database (to store database)

**This server will have as many clones as necessary*

Illustrated as a lifespan of the request:

```
App Request
    |
   CDN
    |
  Load
Balancer
    |
Web head 1   (--   Web head 2   --   Web head 3   --   ...)
    |  \
    |   \
    |    \
    |    Session Server
    |
  Redis      (--    Redis 2     --    Redis 3     --   ...)
    |
 Database
```

---

## Questions

1. Is this a feasible and effective way to layout my server for scalability? Is there something missing in my steps, or do I have surplus?
2. For parsing the XML data into database A every 30 seconds, is PHP competent or should I use another language (Python for example)?
3. For the data that is read, modified and then inputted into database B, is PHP the best solution or should I be using another language for this too?
4. I've looked into multiple servers/NoDB solutions and database caching solutions (Elasticsearch, Redis, Memcached etc). What would be most efficient for this setup?

Again, if you require any more information please ask. If there is a better StackExchange site (I've had a look and couldn't find one) or a better forum in which I should post, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer, rather than a comment - but really, your question is almost impossible to answer.

Your scalability depends on caching - which in turn depends on cache hit ratios. If every user in

> Front-end
>
> ```
> User runs and signs into app
> App periodically makes calls to API to retrieve/push data to database B
> ```
>
> runs the same query, your cache hit ratio will be amazing, and you can do what you want, because your CDN should be able to deal with it all. If they all run different queries, your CDN isn't doing you many favours (how often will the same user re-run the same query), and you have a potential scalability nightmare.

PHP is perfectly fine at parsing XML - most interpreted languages use a native XML parser, so you won't get much benefit from switching languages in most cases.

Question 3: it depends on what the transformation is. If it's just format translation, PHP is fine; if you're doing complex mathematical work, you might benefit from a compiled language (like C/C++) - but the complexity increases fairly dramatically.

Question 4: it all depends on cache hit ratios. Your CDN should bear most of the burden if you design the application right, and your queries are indeed cacheable. If they're not cacheable, no architecture will help.